# Is there a nodequeue module for ordering and selcting taxonomy terms instead of nodes for used in a view?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, javascript, nodes

Currently I want to make a curated slideshow of taxonomy terms displaying the name of the term with an image field thats attached to the term. Typically this is easily done with a basic node and the module nodequeue. The thing is I want to be able to do this with taxonomy terms.

I found entityqueue module that could work, but its crashing on my site for some reason. It works on a new install and I cannot pin point the issue since the site is fully built out already. I was wondering what other ways or possible modules I can do this with?

What I'm building is just a curated slideshow view of taxonomy terms.

*edit -- found the culprit module that was conflicting with the entityqueue module. whenever i turn on the entityqueue module the entire site would crash and i would end up having to do a DB restore. The module that was causing this conflict was "admin_menu"! O_O

Comment: Alternatively, you maybe able to use draggbleviews ( https://drupal.org/project/draggableviews ) to give your slideshow a particular order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out [Flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) module, which supports flagging entities, combined with [flag_weights](https://drupal.org/project/flag_weights) and [draggableviews](https://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) you can create ordered slideshows of flagged taxonomy terms.

> Flag is a flexible flagging system that is completely customizable by the administrator. Using this module, the site administrator can provide any number of flags for nodes, comments, users, and any other type of entity. Some possibilities include bookmarks, marking important, friends, or flag as offensive. With extensive views integration, you can create custom lists of popular content or keep tabs on important content.

If you want to use Flag-3.x with flag_weights you will have to apply this patch: https://drupal.org/node/1877304 works for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

Entityqueue is a great module for this purpose. Draggable Views is a great alternative. You can also check out the [Comparison of Node/Entity Ordering Modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/398508) page on Drupal.org for other options.

**Sidenote:**

The issue mentioned with Entityqueue and Admin Menu was fixed.

This patch was committed to Entityqueue about the time this question was asked, to avoid problems like the one caused by Admin Menu:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2167037#comment-8361729

A patch was later committed to Admin Menu to fix the root cause.